# Proposition II.3.2 of Hartshorne and quasi-compactness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Proposition II.3.2 of Hartshorne book "algebraic geometry". 
The goal is to show that any open affine subscheme of a locally noetherian scheme is noetherian.

At first, I assumed a scheme $X$ is the spectrum of $A$ and noetherian, and I showed $A$ is noetherian.
Secondly, I let $X$ locally noetherian and $U$ the spectrum of $A$ which is open in $X$.
I understood $U$ is locally noetherian but I don't know it is quasi-compact. Replacing the first case doesn't mean that any open affine is quasi-compact, does it? Then how can I get over here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you expecting that we all have access to a copy of Hartshorne's textbook?

Comment: Please copy the proposition (or the part that is relevant for the question) so that this question becomes self-contained.

Comment: You are right. I added the goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every affine scheme is quasi-compact.  Indeed, a collection of basic open sets $D(f_i)$ cover $\operatorname{Spec} A$ iff there is no prime ideal that contains all the elements $f_i$.  This just means that the ideal $I$ generated by the elements $f_i$ is the entire ring $A$.  An ideal $I$ is the entire ring iff $1\in I$.  But if $1\in I$, then $1$ is a linear combination of the generators $f_i$, and this linear combination involves only finitely many of the generators.  So, there are finitely many $f_{i_1},\dots,f_{i_n}$ which generate $A$ as an ideal, which then means that $D(f_{i_1}),\dots,D(f_{i_n})$ cover $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and are a finite subcover of our original cover.

Comment: Oh, it was the property of affine schemes! Thanks, I'll make a note of this.